# Searchlogic Results Duplicating with Each Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, searchlogic

When I chain searchlogix conditions that associate different tables, the results duplicate.

When I chain searchlogix conditions querying fields from a single table, the results work perfectly.

Below is an example of chaining conditions across multiple tables (machine belongs to a manufacturer and machine habtm tools and systems).

```
Machine.manufacturer_id_equals(params[:search][:manufacturer]) \
.tools_id_equals(params[:search][:tools]) \
.systems_id_equals(params[:search][:systems]
```

In this query, only 1 valid result should be returned but the same row is returned 8 times (the total results seem to double with each new condition searching different tables).

I assume there is so problem with join, associations, etc.

Update: It appears that (repetitive) results are being returned. Let's say there are 2 valid machine matches. However, the query is returning a match for each tool and system that is related to the machine. So if the machine has 2 tools and 2 systems, it is returned 4 times.

The temporary fix is to call uniq on the returned array, eliminating the repetitive results. However, this feels bad and almost certainly won't scale.

Can anyone provide guidance? Thank you.